# Matching Syllables and the Note

Tags: python

Example: Say I have 4 notes

```
[A,B,C,D]
```

And I have 6 syllables

```
[hi, my, name, is bob, by]
```

How do I make it so that I loop the 4 notes over and over again until it has assigned a note to the syllable? So

```
hi=a, my=b, name=c, is=d, bob=a, by= a
```

?

I have something like this:

```
for i in range(0, index):
  print(Notes[i], Syllables[i])
```

Comment: Should there be a comma between `is` and `bob`? And should `by = b`?

Comment: Well the question seems to be incomplete. `by=a` made it more confusing. Shouldn't there `by=b`?

Answer (score 1):

Use `itertools`. For example:

```
# two lists of strings
notes = ['A','B','C','D']
syllables = ['hi', 'my', 'name', 'is', 'bob', 'by']

# import cycle from itertools
from itertools import cycle
# create an iterator
cycled = cycle(notes) 

# loop through and output what you requested
for i in range(len(syllables)):
    print(syllables[i], next(cycled))
```

This outputs:

```
'hi' 'A'
'my' 'B'
'name' 'C'
'is' 'D'
'bob' 'A'
'by' 'B'
```

Comment: I would have answered the same, but according to the OP's example, `by` should go with `A`...

Comment: Good point. I figured it was a mistake, since there were a few other errors like you pointed out. If the OP clarifies how the "notes" are assigned I'll change my answer.